# ¿Cómo imprimir un double sin redondear?

Tags: java, double

Estoy intentando meter `999999999999.999999` (es decir, 12 nueves + 6 nueves) en un campo de un registro y, como era de esperar, me lo redondea a `1000000000000` (13 dígitos).

Estuve intentando todo lo que me encontré por aquí (aunque eran para dejar en 2 o 3 decimales), pero aún así, me lo redondea.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola CrisCrina, te recomiendo editar la pregunta y agregar el código que tienes, para poder darte una mejor respuesta, tambien evitarás recibir votos negativos y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: La respuesta es trivial, redactando.

Comment: Bueno, la respuesta es trivial, pero me estoy encontrando con que explicarlo de manera sencilla se complica debido a las matemáticas de conversión implicadas en el proceso. Sigo con la redacción, que ya he cambiado en dos ocasiones para darle diferente enfoque (el más didáctico posible).

Comment: Bastante relacionado: [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](/q/197)

Comment: Resumiendo mucho: con `double` no vas a poder, quizá deberías usar `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 2):

El problema es no es posible asignar el valor deseado a una variable `double` sin pérdida de precisión.

Antes de continuar, te recomiendo leer el tema de la precisión en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) para conocer la manera en la que se codifica un valor `double` en memoria:

> *v = (-1)<sup>s</sup> x c x 2<sup>q</sup>*
>
> E<sub>min</sub> = -(2<sup>K-1</sup>-2) | E<sub>max</sub> = 2<sup>K-1</sup>-1

Donde:

- *s*: bit de signo.
- *c*: valor entero (<2<sup>N</sup>).
- *q*: exponente (entre E<sub>max</sub> y E<sub>min</sub>).

Nota: un mismo valor se podría codificar de múltiples maneras diferentes con estos parámetros, por lo que se considera que un valor doble está *normalizado* si el valor de `c` es < 2<sup>N-1</sup>.

Los valores de `N` y `K` se muestran en la siguiente tabla:

| Parameter | double |
| --- | --- |
| N | 53 |
| K | 11 |
| E<sub>max</sub> | +1023 |
| E<sub>min</sub> | -1022 |

---

Nota: esta es una respuesta simplificada sin llevar a cabo una conversión completa con exponente de base 2.

De modo que para representar un valor disponemos de 52 bits de datos para almacenar el valor:

> 2<sup>52</sup> = 4 503 599 627 370 496 ≈ 4.5 E+15

Lo que equivaldría a unas 15 cifras decimales completas.

El número deseado es:

```
999999999999.999999
```

Representado en manera científica tendríamos:

```
999 999 999 999 999 999 E-6
```

Que, como puede verse, tiene 18 cifras decimales, por lo que no es posible codificar ese número sin pérdida en un valor doble, ya que no podría alojarse de ninguna forma correcta tantos bits de datos en solo 52 bits. Por este motivo el valor se aproxima al valor más cercano que sí es posible codificar con esa cantidad de bits de datos.

Además, como he puesto en la nota, esta es una simplificación/aproximación sin hacer la conversión real a un número normalizado con un exponente de base 2 (y no en base 10). Esto significa que, por poner un ejemplo, algo tan sencillo como multiplicar o dividir entre 1000, para agregar o quitar 3 posiciones decimales, lo más aproximado en base 2 sería hacerlo por 1024, que equivale a agregar o quitar 10 posiciones decimales en base 2 (y no 3 como sería en base 10).